# WP finally live: How to edit style.css on the fly and live (Theme Editor?) and immediately see changes + caching

Tags: wordpress

I developed my WP WooCommerce shop locally with XAMPP and finally got around to upload my site.

1) How do you make edits to your CSS when the site is live and online?
Do you use Appearance > Theme Editor to make changes to your `style.css` file that is saved in your child theme or is there a plugin that is "better" than the default one? 
Is there a shortcut for commenting lines out?
Or do you have an identical version locally that is synced to the uploaded version and do the edits locallly and upload the final edited `style.css` file?
I'm not sure what the best workflow is.

2) I find myself making changes and nothing happens on the live site. Do I have to clear the cache and than login again to get into my WP dashboard? Seems very tedious... I searched the forum and found that you can do something with this line

```
wp_enqueue_style( '_s-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), time() );
```

can someone elaborate how and where to use it? does it go into the functions file?

Answer (score 0):

Use this line your functions.php

```
function yourthemename_style_nscripts(){
    wp_enqueue_style( '_s-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), time() );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'yourthemename_style_nscripts');
```

otherwise, 
open your functions.php then find your yourthemename_style_nscripts function then paste it.